# CoCos2D Intersection of non-rectangular sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite with a triangle shape and I want to know when this triangle intersects with another object (a CCSPrite). I have been using `CGRectIntersectsRect` but it is not accurate because it take the bounding box of the the two sprites and not the actual shape.

--Edit

I think one way is to define several points around the actual triangle and check intersection between those points with another sprite. I am just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box2d to detect collisions accurately. It can be useful if you have many different complicated shapes. Or you can just check intersections of shape's edges.

If there is many objects to detect collisions with, I offer to use box2d. It has good internal optimizations to be able to work with large amount of objects. In this case you will just have to create physical body equal to the your sprite's shape before adding object to your game layer.

Comment: dang... i started my project without box2d+cocos2d ... is there a way to add it after starting only with cocos2d?

Comment: of course =) any template just have some predefined declarations and initializations. you always can add them by yourself. you can find a lot of articles of adding box2d to your project and how to use it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think I am going to go with my approach of introducing several CGPoints in my object. I think introducing Box2D just for this purpose is too much?

Comment: maybe. as i mentioned in my post, box2d is very good when you have a lot of objects and you need to detect collisions for all of them. In case of several objects it is excessive